# org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor - Error finishing response after migration to jdk11

Tags: java, tomcat, java-11

After service migration jdk8 -> jdk11 strange error occurs. 
Moreover, there no impact on the service itself. It works as expected

I want to understand what's causing this error and how to fix it

```java
[http-nio-8081-exec-1] ERROR org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor - Error finishing response[]

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.MimeHeaders.setValue(MimeHeaders.java:319)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.prepareResponse(Http11Processor.java:886)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.action(AbstractProcessor.java:369)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.endRequest(Http11Processor.java:1112)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:448)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: What version of Tomcat are you using?

Comment: Tomcat version: 9

Comment: What is the full version?  I cannot look at the source code of org.apache.tomcat.util.http.MimeHeaders, much less understand what is happening at line 319, unless I know which version of the source code to look at.

Comment: I use embedded tomcat with this version `https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/2.1.3.RELEASE`